# Bash command to remove and add lines in a file?

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a large file on a linux server. The same file is on a linux client.
The server file will be modified on a regular basis. I'd like to be able to download only the changes and apply them to the file on the client. I'm wondering if there is some built in linux command(s) for doing such a thing.  Unfortunately, I don't believe rsync is an option.  The "client" is an embedded version of linux which has the following:

```
 [, [[, arping, ash, awk, basename, brctl, bunzip2, bzcat, cat, chgrp, chmod, chown, chroot, clear, cmp, cp, crond,
    crontab, cut, date, dd, df, dirname, dmesg, du, echo, egrep, env, expr, false, fgrep, find, free, fsync, grep, gunzip,
    gzip, halt, head, hexdump, hostid, hwclock, id, ifconfig, init, insmod, kill, killall, klogd, less, ln, lock, logger,
    logread, ls, lsmod, md5sum, mkdir, mkfifo, mknod, mktemp, mount, mv, nc, netmsg, netstat, nice, nslookup, ntpd, passwd,
    pgrep, pidof, ping, ping6, pivot_root, pkill, poweroff, printf, ps, pwd, reboot, reset, rm, rmdir, rmmod, route, sed,
    seq, sh, sleep, sort, start-stop-daemon, strings, switch_root, sync, sysctl, syslogd, tail, tar, tee, telnet, telnetd,
    test, time, top, touch, tr, traceroute, true, udhcpc, umount, uname, uniq, uptime, vconfig, vi, watchdog, wc, wget,
    which, xargs, yes, zcat
```

I'm wondering if the most efficient option is to create a file on the server that has any new lines in the file start with a "+", any removed lines start with a "-", and any modified lines be both "-" and "+"...and then somehow get awk, sed, and/or grep to update the file according to the "diff" file. I can't imagine that what I'm doing is that unique. Any pointers?

Comment: why don't you use git?

Comment: How about using `diff` and `patch`?

Comment: Good suggestions.  I'll look into those.  They aren't already installed on my embedded device but I may be able to install them if they are pretty small.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with `diff` and `patch`.  These old-school tools are tiny and widely available.  I'd use them this way:

```
# server:
diff -wu oldfile newfile > file.patch

# now copy the patch file from server to client

# client:
patch < file.patch
```

Easy as that.  But you can get quite a bit fancier with various options (I just showed ignoring whitespace with -w).

Comment: `-w` is a bad idea if you're making patches. It can make patches which do not apply properly.  I also don't see any evidence in the question that the text file is in a language or format in which no whitespace whatsoever is significant.